# OracleDependency doesn't fire event

Tags: .net, oracle, notifications

I want to create a listener to Oracle DB on table changes for table x that its values change according to insert/update to table y so I wrote the following code :

```
public static OracleDependency dependency;
    private static OracleConnection con;
    private static OracleCommand cmd;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        con = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBString"]].ConnectionString);
        cmd = new OracleCommand(
                                      "select * from X ", con ) ;

        con.Open();
        //OracleDependency.Port = 23;
        //OracleDependency.Address = "11.10.11.1";

        cmd.AddRowid = true;

        dependency = new OracleDependency(cmd);
        dependency.OnChange += Dependency_OnChange;

        bool IsNotified = false;

        dependency.QueryBasedNotification = true;

        cmd.Notification.IsNotifiedOnce = false;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //con.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("Listeneing to DB....");

        // Loop while waiting for notification
        while (IsNotified == false)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
     }

    private static void Dependency_OnChange(object sender, OracleNotificationEventArgs args)
    {
        DataTable dt = args.Details;
        string msg = string.Empty;
        msg = "THe following DB objects were changed";
        foreach (string resource in args.ResourceNames)
            msg += resource;

        msg += "\n\n Details";
        for (int i = 1; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            msg += "Resource Name: " + dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0];
            string type = Enum.GetName(typeof(OracleNotificationInfo), dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[1]);
            msg += "\nchange type: " + type;
            Console.WriteLine(msg);
        }
    }
```

And when I select entry in user_change_notification_regs , I see entry is added but as soon as any transaction is committed, the entry is removed and the notification event is not fired, anything wrong with the code ?